# Adding intraday option to highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Would like to add an intraday (1 day) zoom option to the following chart. I'd like to see an example of how to do this in combination with the zoom options already available - http://jsfiddle.net/cvezpup7/1/

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length,
            // set the allowed units for data grouping
            groupingUnits = [[
                'week',                         // unit name
                [1]                             // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]],

            i = 0;

        for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }

        var minOHLC = Math.min.apply(Math, ohlc.map(function(v) { return v[3] > 0 ? v[3] : 99999999 }))

        var maxOHLC = Math.max.apply(Math, ohlc.map(function(v) { return v[2]}))

        var maxVolume = Math.max.apply(Math, volume.map(function(v) { return v[1]}))

        var maxVolumeHeight = maxVolume / (minOHLC / maxOHLC)

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                inputEnabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },           
            yAxis: [{
                lineWidth: 0
            }, {
                max: maxVolumeHeight,
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 0,
               // gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels:
                {
                  enabled: false
                }
            }],

           series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your own [buttons](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.buttons) arrays:

```
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            },{
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'ytd',
                text: 'YTD'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }]
```

Note, that with this dataset the most granular Highstock will let you go is 5 days.  See details [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2187).

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvezpup7/2/).

Comment: The volume chart from the bottom seems to be missing in the '5 day' zoom option.

Comment: @JamieWhite, it's there, the volume value for those 5 days is so low, the bar height is not render-able.  Here's a fiddle where I've artificially upped the value:  http://jsfiddle.net/cvezpup7/3/